# access state from within component class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react, 
I am trying to use state to replace native JS DOM calls update DOM from inside a method.
I can't seem to get it to work. It keeps saying this.setState is not a function.
this is my current code below:

```
class AddMsg extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {uploadBar: 'hide'};
  }
  ...
  handleSubmit(e) {
    ...
     if (file !== '' && this.state.chars_left >= 0) {
       ...
       uploadTask.on('state_changed', function (snapshot) {
         ...
        let progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        (progress < 100)
          ? this.setState({uploadBar: 'show'})
          : this.setState({uploadBar: 'hide'})
        }, function error(err) {
         ...
       }, function complete() {
         ... 
       }
       ...
  }
  render(){
    return(
      ...
      <span className={`help is-primary has-text-centered ${this.state.uploadBar}`}> Sending scribe now...</span>
    )
  }
}
```

the code I am trying to replace...

```
    (progress < 100)
      ? document.getElementById('uploadBar').style.display = 'block'
      : document.getElementById('uploadBar').style.display = 'none';
```

anyone got any suggestions? 
Like I said I keep getting setState is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use arrow function to widen the access scope of your callback function:

```
uploadTask.on('state_changed', (snapshot) => {
     ...
    let progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    (progress < 100)
      ? this.setState({uploadBar: 'show})
      : this.setState({uploadBar: 'hide})
})
```

You also forgot the closing quotes after show and hide. I think you meant to write:

```
this.setState({uploadBar: 'show'})
this.setState({uploadBar: 'hide'})
```

Comment: That works, thanks and thanks for pointing out the mistake, have fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You need to `bind` this callback:

```
uploadTask.on('state_changed', function (snapshot) {
    ...
}.bind(this));
```

Otherwise, you don't have the context where `this.setState` exists.  Since the callback is called by something outside the current context, you must bind manually if you want `this` to resolve correctly.

Comment: thanks Davin this will work as well. I chose to use the ES6 version as suggested by   guitoof above